# iTextsharp crop ImportedPage and align right on new page

Tags: c#, itext, crop

I have to clear/delete the left margin of pdf files, so that the left margin (12mm) has only a transparent background.

I’ll tryed to paint a white rectangle, but the left margin has to be transparent.

My current approach is, cutting all content beginning with an offset of 12mm (Rectangle cropbox). The result is that all the content is aligned left. 
Has anybody an idea how to align it on the right?

Thanks for help.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (Document doc = new Document())
    {
        using (PdfSmartCopy pdfSmartCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, stream))
        {                 
            doc.Open();

            PdfContentByte cb = pdfSmartCopy.DirectContent;

            PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < m_MergeFileList.Count; i++)
            {
                MergeFileList mfl = m_MergeFileList[i];

                PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

                using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(mfl.FilePath))
                {
                    if (reader.NumberOfPages > 0)
                    {
                        List<int> lPages = CRangeParser.ParseRange(mfl.CopyPages, 1, reader.NumberOfPages);

                        if (lPages.Count != 0)
                        {
                            foreach (int iPage in lPages)
                            {

                                importedPage = pdfSmartCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, iPage);

                                if (true)
                                {
                                    PdfDictionary pdfDictionary = reader.GetPageN(iPage);
                                    PdfArray cropArray = new PdfArray();
                                    PdfArray cropArrayOrg = new PdfArray();
                                    Rectangle cropbox = reader.GetCropBox(iPage);
                                    cropArray.Add(new PdfNumber(cropbox.GetLeft((72f / 25.4f) * 12.5f)));
                                    cropArray.Add(new PdfNumber(cropbox.GetBottom(0f)));
                                    cropArray.Add(new PdfNumber(cropbox.GetLeft((72f / 25.4f) * 12.5f) + cropbox.Width));
                                    cropArray.Add(new PdfNumber(cropbox.GetBottom(0f) + cropbox.Height));

                                    pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, cropArray);
                                    pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, cropArray); //cropArray);
                                    //pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.TRIMBOX, cropArray);
                                    //pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.BLEEDBOX, cropArray);
                                    /*
                                    PdfSmartCopy.PageStamp stamp = pdfSmartCopy.CreatePageStamp(importedPage);
                                    PdfContentByte cb = stamp.GetOverContent();

                                    cb.Rectangle(0, 0, (72f / 25.4f) * 12.5f, importedPage.Height);
                                    cb.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.WHITE);
                                    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
                                    cb.FillStroke();
                                    stamp.AlterContents();
                                    */
                                }

                                importedPage = pdfSmartCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, iPage);
                                pdfSmartCopy.AddPage(importedPage);

                                totalPages++;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bResult = false;
                        }

                        pdfSmartCopy.FreeReader(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bResult = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading your question, I understand that you want to clip. Reading your code, I see that you crop. Your problem is that you confuse clipping with cropping. In other words: you'll have to throw away all the code you have right now and start anew now that you know that you want to clip, not to crop.

Comment: I think there's some other things that need to be explained/understood, too. The "whiteness" of a "margin" is really an artifact of the renderer (Adobe Reader, etc) and doesn't exist in the PDF, so there really isn't anything white that can be replaced or masked. Also, the various boxes (CROP, MEDIA) are hints to renderers for what to show. If you set the crop box, you aren't actually cropping as you would in Photoshop but are instead instructing renderers to not show that area.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie
Yes, i´m really confused. I have see some examples to clip images, but not complete pdf pages. Have you some example code for me to merge xx pdf to one with clipping? Big thanks for hint/help.

Comment: If it's OK to lose all interactive features, I'd use `PdfWriter` and import pages as `PdfImportedPage` objects. When adding these objects with `addTemplate()`, I'd clip them. Or I'd wrap the pages inside an `Image` object and clip the image. Googling for these keywords should result in examples available on itextpdf.com

Comment: I have write now the code for the clipping and it work, but one problem i have. We have replaced in the source PDF a telephone number with a with box and write over there the new phone number. In the target is the wrong number. Have can take the comments to the target file.